# Office 365: How to fetch deleted Calendar Events using REST API?

Tags: office365, office365-restapi

Even after going through the REST API document several times, I could not find a way to fetch Deleted events from Office365. Is there a way to get them?

Also in the document under "[Sync Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#Syncevents)" it says all the events Created, Updated and Deleted in user's calendar is fetched. But still I am not getting any deleted events.

Answer (score 2):

No, the API does not return deleted events. Once they are deleted, they are no longer a part of the results.

For sync, you will get a delete entry with only the item's ID if you previously synced that item and then the user deletes it. It doesn't return all deleted events, only ones that are relevant to your sync state.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation.

Comment: Our application is currently using normal fetch API to get Events and Contacts from Office 365. But now if we switch our APIs to SYNC API will there be any problem for the records that are already fetched? Will the SYNC API send deleted records if we switch our APIs?

Comment: We are currently using GET api to pull Events. As it would not fetch deleted events, we have to use Sync api to pull deleted events.

Information related to Sync API is not clear in official docs i.e are data getting pulled based in LastModifiedTime field or not.  Will sync api always return modified, created and deleted records with the time range? Will sync api return nextLink (skip token) when there are no modified records available?